# Is it possible to migrate from cucumber-jvm to QAF?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, qaf

we already have automated testcases using cucumber-gherkin feature files with WebDriver. 
Right now we are able to execute feature files parallel, however we are not able to execute parallel at scenario/scenario outline level.
By this way we want to minimize the execution time and utilize the cloud service at maximum level.

I read this [post](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf-gherkin-client.html), which claims

> one can run gherkin as QAF scenario so it will have features like run
>   configuration, reporting, parallel execution, step listener

.

Before migrating, I want to know if anybody has tried or know any limitation as our test bed is very large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with QMetry Automation Framework you can execute parallel at scenario/scenario outline level with without any change in your feature files.

**If you have used any cucumber hooks it will not work**. For that you can provide TestNG listener to achieve the same goal. You will get more listener support from TestNG and QAF listeners which may not be achievable with cucumber hooks.

Another difference, which in fact not a limitation, is For execution instead of --tag you need to use TestNG groups filter and provide your tags as group.  For Example:

```
<groups>
    <run>
        <exclude name="@MyTag" />
    </run>
</groups>
```

Go ahead and give it try without any fear. For quick evaluation, you can [download example](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/releases/download/2.1.9-RC2/QAFGherkin.zip) and check.  While using cucumber you will get many more features with QAF for execution as well as for new development of new test case like databean, data-providers, custom-components etc...

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded example and executed it. It has resolved my issue. I have seen reports as well which is more descriptive to understand all details about scenario, scenario outline.

Comment: @user861594 I've downloaded the example project & I see there is a `QAFPerfectoCucumberFormatter.java-ex` file. I believe this acts as a plugin for `CucumberRunner.java` however when I try to execute the `CucumberRunner.java` ,it fails with `cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.qmetry.qaf.examples.cucumber.runners.QAFPerfectoCucumberFormatter` could you please tell me if i need to rename `QAFPerfectoCucumberFormatter.java-ex` to `QAFPerfectoCucumberFormatter.java` ? how do I execute custom cucumberrunner ? Thanks for any help

Comment: You can delete cucumber/runner folder (com.qmetry.qaf.examples.cucumber.runners), it is unused code , not required at all, missed to clean up.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I've upgraded to latest QAF version however when I using testNG annotations in step definition class, it doesn't get triggered. QAF only supports `@Given`@then` `@when` & not the cucumber hooks. Have you tried making use of testNG annotations in your step def instead of cucumber hooks?

Comment: Did you registered TestNG Listener? Refer http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners. When using QAF you can have additional QAF listeners as well. Refer https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we recently evaluated QMetry Automation Framework gherkin feature with one of our existing project where we have cucumber tests and it took us less than one hour to configure. It worked fine for us. For us we were using QAF for other projects (without cucumber) so we have good understanding of other features. If you are new it may take a day or two but for long term it is worth.