# JUnit implementation of QAF

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, qaf

Good afternoon.
Is it possible to implement the work of QAF with JUnit?
For example, i want to use [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) in my project, but it's build on JUnit + Cucumber.
As I see, there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899242/is-it-possible-to-migrate-from-cucumber-jvm-to-qaf), but there is no description about project and on which test framework it was based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QAF built upon TestNG. If you are using Junit for Java you can run using TestNG by setting `junit="true"` in configuration file. However for migrating cucumber to QAF it should not impact current runner is either Junit or TestNG until you are using any specific features of Junit. All you need to start using QAF following [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html#for-existing-cucumber-implementation). You don't need to write or use additional java class to run your tests because it is taken care by QAF. All you need to do is create xml [configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) file for to run your [BDD](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html)

Because QAF provides all testing needs together you don't need to relay on multiple frameworks (junit and cucumber in your case).

Comment: Thanks. Also, can you recommend more frameworks with the ability to define custom dataproviders as cucumber examples?
As i checked google, there are only qaf and noraui

Comment: I am not sure about other frameworks but i know that qaf is used in many organizations as that enterprise standard for web, mobile, webservice testing and test written in java, bdd or keyword driven way employing different design concepts like databean, custom component, teststep, testpage, locator repository etc

Comment: Thanks. Back to main question: during the migration to the qaf-gherkin we indicate the class in testng xml that works with the cucumber (   <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
)
But how to specify a class in which Before/After methods are stored? If you set it in the testng "class" config, then the tests will be executed two times, and in one case, feature files will not be found, and the other will not work Before/After methods

Comment: You need to use testng before and after annotations. Add that class in addition to factory. May be you can ask separate question explaining problem.

Comment: With latest [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber) you can use qaf with junit+cucumber